# ios Google Geocoding API

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

I ran "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true" in iPhone project for getting coordinate of `"1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA"`.
But I got the response:

> "REQUEST_DENIED"

I didn't find why this error occured.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Works for me. Check the docs for possible reasons. Perhaps you made too many requests in too short a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone.html), it's very helpful...hopefully it helps you out

Comment: How to Search Google Places when i click on textFieldand want to show results just below textField. I am using Swift 3.0 version.Could someone help me @PTBG

Comment: This is not an answer @PTBG

Answer (score 0):

```
They are different versions available
Address for geocoding -> ”http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" // here you put your address then add the key
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=" // no need for key just add the address
for any address lookup
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="
```